# SQL query that distinguishes between ß and ss

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, collation

It seems that `ß=ss` in SQL. I need to be able to distinguish on a strict charcter equivalent basis.

i.e. `SELECT * from table WHERE name LIKE '%ß%'`

yields

`Brian Bruß`
`Steven Sossmix`

etc..

I've looked at different Collations to see if there is one that ignores character expansions, but no luck so far.

Database has `Latin1_General_CI_AS` as default - I've also tried `Latin1_General_CS_AS` and `Latin1_General_CS_AS_WS`, neither of which worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which database server are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or...?

Comment: And what are the localization settings - which code set and collation is in force by default.

Comment: I get your results when I prefix ss with N. -> N'ss' otherwise it works as expected (for me).

Comment: @jms-it deals with what the cultureInfo is set to

Comment: Great edge case, thanks for posting. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a binary collation so that it's case-sensitive, accent-sensitive, etc.

Collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN`

Answer (score 1):

Found a [thread](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:y3MXY4nbuy8J:www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/56/284342.aspx+sql+difference+between+%C3%9F+and+ss+in+sql+server+2008&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) that has two solutions for this.

Comment: One answer was from Jon Skeet, so maybe he could step in and elaborate on it