# Getting primary key Violation for two different VARCHAR values

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, data-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query that distinguishes between ß and ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772763/sql-query-that-distinguishes-between-ss-and-ss)

This is probably some weird encoding issue but I have no idea how to fix it.

I have a primary key column which is VARCHAR(50). If I insert

```
dass
```

and then I insert

```
daß
```

then SQL Server loses its mind and throws Primary Key Violation errors. This also happens if I use .Net's DataTable class.

Here is a little script so you can test it out yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    Word varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE Foo ADD  CONSTRAINT PK_Foo PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Word] ASC
)

INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('dass')
INSERT INTO Foo VALUES ('daß')
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this? I tried to make the column NCHAR and that didn't work.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it looks like you're running into  http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-server/355631-ss-they-equal.html

Comment: Found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772763/sql-query-that-distinguishes-between-ss-and-ss