# Why 'Weiss'='Weiß' or search in SQL Server over Unicode column

Tags: c#, sql-server, unicode

I have column in SQL Server defined as `nvarchar` and as a result (I think) 'Weiss'=='Weiß'.  But in my c# code 'Weiss'!='Weiß'

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tags]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](125) NOT NULL,
    [IsBlocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Updated] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tags] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Tags]
WHERE Value = 'Weiss Kreuz'
```

returns row where value is 'Weiß Kreuz'

Can someone explain how that happen and how to make comparison the same in c# and SQL Server?

Comment: Have you tried a case insensitive equals?

Comment: in sql or c#?  No.  somehow sql 'ss' makes equal to 'ß'

Comment: In C#. SQL is often configured to do case insensitive string comparisons while C# usually dose case sensitive ones.

Answer (score 6):

As you probably know that [the German letter eszett (ß)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) in some words is used instead of double-s in German. So if you do a UNICODE comparison of the words *Weiss* and *Weiß* (meaning *White*) they are considered the same.

In C# you can do a UNICODE comparison (also described as a culture sensitive comparison) using [`String.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
String.Compare("Weiss", "Weiß")
```

This will return 0 indicating that the two strings are equal.

Using the equals operator:

```
"Weiss" == "Weiß"
```

returns false but this operator uses a culture insensitive comparison.

[SQL Server handles sorting and comparison of strings using a collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx). Earlier versions of SQL Server used rules that were different compared to the rules used by Windows (and thus .NET/C#) but now the SQL Server collations have been aligned with the UNICODE rules in Windows.

> This provides consistency across data types within SQL Server, and it also lets developers sort strings in their applications by using the same rules that are used by SQL Server.

Comment: In C#, with `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` (for all cultures I know) and `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` the two values are considered the same, while for `StringComparison.Ordinal` they are clearly distinct. The default for `Compare` and `CompreTo` is to use the current culture. The default for `==` and `Equals` is to use the ordinal comparison. Again, this comment is about C# only.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The comment you made isn't for C#, it's for .NET, because the .NET libraries are done that way. If you wanted a Jeppe# language to do it differently, you would need your Jeppe# compiler to catch all the calls to the string== and string.Equal methods and redirect them to some other methods.

Comment: @xanatos Correct. Thank you for making that clear! The only thing that is specific to C# is the operator `bool operator ==(string x, string y)` which is technically not a [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) method. Everything else I mentioned is about the .NET library in general.

Comment: @Jeppe It is even bigger than that... Even the `operator==` is part of .NET ... Look at the IL code: http://goo.gl/cJTJfG : `call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string) `

Comment: @xanatos Oh, I was wrong about that one too. You are right, and [that method is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx), of course. I think I confused it with the overload `bool operator ==(object x, object y)` which is not a real method on `System.Object` or elsewhere. But that overload is not relevant here of course.

Comment: how to make my SQL behave like c#?  I don't want C# to behave like SQL by using String.Compare("Weiss", "Weiß") but I want SQL to return false on "Weiss" == "Weiß"

Comment: @Cherven: You should be able to use the [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) keyword specifying a [binary collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143350(v=sql.105).aspx) in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the collation and on how the comparison is done:

```
string str1 = "Weiss";
string str2 = "Weiß";
bool res = string.Compare(str1, str2) == 0;
bool res2 = string.Equals(str1,str2,StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
```

where `string.Compare` returns `0` if the two strings are equal.

From [string.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn:

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of individual characters

and [string.Equals(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison.

and [string.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The comparisonType parameter indicates whether the comparison should use the current or invariant culture, honor or ignore the case of the two strings being compared, or use word or ordinal sort rules.

If you look around (e.g. [SQL query that distinguishes between ß and ss](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772763/613130)), you will see that it's known that in many sql collations `ss == ß`.

**In general** you shouldn't reorder client-side things ordered by SQL, nor you should recompare client-side things compared by SQL, because the collation of SQL and the collation of .NET are different for small things (often because they use different versions of Unicode, or because for compatibility reasons they do things differently)