# German Collation comparision as Nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing an issue while comparing two strings, one with Germany special character 'ß' and other is with normal character 'ss'. My Database is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" collation which should compare these characters and it is doing as expected only when I compare them as hardcoded string. However when I use cast to convert them into NVARCHAR then it treat them equal. I don't understand why changing the type should impact. Below is my example .

```sql
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'DBName';

/**/

IF CAST('Steds.Weßels' AS NVARCHAR(100)) = CAST('Steds.Wessels' AS NVARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SELECT 'Equal'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 'Not equal'
END

/**/

IF 'Steds.Weßels' = 'Steds.Wessels'
BEGIN
SELECT 'Equal'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 'Not equal'
END
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Why 'Weiss'='Weiß' or search in SQL Server over Unicode column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29045662/2029983)

Comment: This `CAST('Steds.Weßels' ...` is already wrong. You need to write unicode constants by [prefacing the string with N](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That would actually make the `CAST`ing point there, @SMor . For the example the OP has, `ß` can be represented by a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Changing from Nvarchar to Varchar finally solve this issue. Below is the link for details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/327844/german-collation-comparision-as-nvarchar.html