# Choosing a binary collation that can differentiate between 'ss' and 'ß' for nvarchar column in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, collation, sql-server-2016

As the default `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation of SQL server can't differentiate between `ss` and `ß`, I want to change the collation of a specific column in a table to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2`, as advised in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772853/2270340).

However, I am not sure whether this is generally a good practice or not. Also I am not sure about the implications other than the following:

- **Changing the sort order:** As I am never sorting the data on this column, it might not be a problem for me. However, if you think otherwise, please let me know.
- **Changing case-insensitivity to case-sensitivity**: As my application always provide text in lowercase, I think this change will also not be a problem for me. However, if you think otherwise, please let me know.

I am curious about the other major implications of this change, if any.

Additionally, I would also like to know which one of the following would be a most suited for this scenario:

> **SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN**
>
> **Description:** Latin1-General, binary sort for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 30 on Code Page 437 for non-Unicode Data
>
> ---
>
> **SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2**
>
> **Description:** Latin1-General, binary code point comparison sort for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 30 on Code Page 437 for non-Unicode Data
>
> ---
>
> **SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN**
>
> **Description:** Latin1-General, binary sort for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 40 on Code Page 850 for non-Unicode Data
>
> ---
>
> **SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2**
>
> **Description:** Latin1-General, binary code point comparison sort for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 40 on Code Page 850 for non-Unicode Data

If you think that there are other collations better suited for this scenario, please mention those as well.

---

**Update on 19.03.2017:**
To anyone coming to this question:

- Must check both the answers from @srutzky and @SqlZim, as well as the related referred resources. You don't want to rush into things in this case.
- As changing collation is not for faint hearted :P, keeping a backup of table data might come in handy.
- Also check the dependencies on column, such as index and constraint; you may need to drop and create those, as it were in my case.

Have fun :)

Comment: Worth taking a look: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322112/comparing-sql-collations-to-windows-collations

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I edited your question title to include the specific issue of 'ss' and 'ß' so that others might find this question more easily in the future.

Comment: @SqlZim Not at all. Thank you for that

Comment: Sorry for the OT comment, but I have to just say - wow! Great question Sayan Pal and greater answers by @ srutzky and @SqlZim !

Comment: @Phylyp and Sayan: I have updated again to add more details to explain points 1 and 2, and added links to point # 4 if anyone wanted to see the difference in those 3 code pages :-) You can see the updates more easily via the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42883638/revisions) page.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A few things about Collations:

1. The `SQL_` Collations were deprecated as of SQL Server 2000 (yes, 2000). If you can avoid using them, you should (but that doesn't mean go changing a bunch of things if there is no pressing need to!).

   The issue with the `SQL_` Collations is really only related to `VARCHAR` (i.e. non-Unicode) data as `NVARCHAR` (i.e. Unicode) data uses the rules from the OS. But the rules for sorting and comparison for `VARCHAR` data, unfortunately, use a simple mapping and do not include the more complex linguistic rules. This is why `ss` and `ß` do not equate when stored as `VARCHAR` using the same `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` Collation. These deprecated Collations also are not able to give a lower weight to dashes when used in the middle of a word. The non-`SQL_` Collations (i.e. Windows Collations) use the same rules for both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` so the `VARCHAR` handling is more robust, more consistent with `NVARCHAR`.
2. The `_BIN` Collations were deprecated as of SQL Server 2005. If you can avoid using them, you should (but that doesn't mean go changing a bunch of things if there is no pressing need to!).

   The issue with the `_BIN` Collations is rather subtle as it only affects sorting. Comparisons are the same between `_BIN` and `_BIN2` Collations due to them being compared at the byte level (hence no linguistic rules). BUT, due to SQL Server (and Windows / PCs) being Little Endian, entities are stored in reverse byte order. This becomes apparent when dealing with double-byte "characters", which is what `NVARCHAR` data is: UTF-16 Little Endian. This means that Unicode Code Point U+1216 has a hex/binary representation of 0x1216 on Big Endian systems, but is stored as 0x1612 on Little Endian systems. To come full circle so that the importance of this last point will (hopefully) become obvious: the `_BIN` Collations will compare byte by byte (after the first character) and hence see U+1216 as being 0x16 and then 0x12, while the `_BIN2` Collations will compare code point by code point and hence see U+1216 as being 0x12 and then 0x16.
3. This particular column is `NVARCHAR` (a `VARCHAR` column using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` would not equate `ss` and `ß`) and so for just this column alone, there is no difference between `SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN2` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2` due to Unicode being a single, all-inclusive character set.
4. For `VARCHAR` data, there would be a difference since they are different code pages ([437](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195060.aspx) and [850](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195064.aspx)), and both of those are different than the one that you are using now (`CP1` == code page [1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx)).
5. While using a binary Collation is often overkill, in this case it might be necessary given that there is only one locale / culture that does not equate `ß` with `ss`: Hungarian. Using a Hungarian Collation might have some linguistic rules that you don't want (or at least wouldn't expect), so the binary Collation seems to be the better choice here (just not any of the 4 you are asking about :-). Just keep in mind that by using a binary Collation, not only are you giving up *all* linguistic rules, but you also lose the ability to equate different versions of the same character, such as `A` ([Latin Capital Letter A U+0041](https://unicode-table.com/en/0041/)) and `Ａ` ([Fullwidth Latin Capital Letter A U+FF21](https://unicode-table.com/en/FF21/)).

   Use the following query to see what Collations are non-binary and do not equate these characters:

   ```
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;';

   SELECT @SQL += REPLACE(N'
     IF(N''ß'' COLLATE {Name} <> N''ss'' COLLATE {Name})
     BEGIN
       RAISERROR(N''%4d.  {Name}'', 10, 1, @Counter) WITH NOWAIT;
       SET @Counter += 1;
     END;
   ', N'{Name}', col.[name]) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
   FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations() col
   WHERE  col.[name] NOT LIKE N'SQL[_]%'
   AND    col.[name] NOT LIKE N'%[_]BIN%'
   ORDER BY col.[name]

   --PRINT @SQL;
   EXEC (@SQL);
   ```

So:

- If you are going to use a binary Collation, use something like `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`.
- You do *not* need to change the Collation of the entire DB and all of its tables. That is *a lot* of work, and the only "built-in" mechanism to do it is undocumented (i.e. unsupported).
- If you were to change the Database's default Collation, that affects name resolution of Database-scoped items such as tables, columns, indexes, functions, stored procedures, etc. Meaning: you would need to regress 100% of the application that touches the database, as well as all SQL Server Agent jobs, etc. that touch this database.
- If most / all of the queries that use this column need `ß` with `ss` to be seen as different, then go ahead and alter the column to use `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`. This will likely require dropping the following dependent objects and then recreating after the `ALTER TABLE`:

  - Indexes
  - Unique Constraints
  - Foreign Key Constraints

  **HINT:** Be sure to check the current NULL / NOT NULL setting of the column and specify that in the `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ...` statement so that it does not get changed.
- If only some queries need this different behavior, then override just those comparison operations with the `COLLATE` clause, on a per-condition basis (e.g. `WHERE tab.[ThisColumn] LIKE N'%ss%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`). The `COLLATE` keyword should only be needed on one side (of the operator) as Collation Precedence will apply it to the other side.

For more info on working with strings and collations, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :)

Comment: Very thorough, and thanks again for responding to the request!

Comment: @SqlZim I see the bounty on the question and wanted to say thanks. That was very kind and unnecessary :-). And because I now feel a little guilty for  taking over and now getting even more points, I went ahead and made it more worth the bonus by adding more info, mostly on points 1 and 2. Plus a few handy links and a hint on the very last item. :-)

Comment: There is no ß in Hungarian. So what's the point in saying that it is the only locale where ß and ss are not equal? There are many other cultures that don't have an ß in their alphabet. Like Switzerland for example.

Comment: @ohgodnotanotherone Most alphabets don't have the `ß` character, but this is Unicode, so the character exists regardless of the locale / culture-specific rules for sorting. Just like all Hebrew, Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, etc characters exist at all times in Unicode. The point is, as stated, that the Hungarian locale is the only non-binary locale in which `ß` does not compare to `ss` as being equal. Hence, using a Hungarian Collation allows for having a good amount of natural language rules (sensitivities, expansions, expected orderings, etc) while being able to distinguish these characters.

Answer (score 7):

In general, `BIN2` would be preferable over `BIN`, and you may want to choose a windows collation over a sql collation. e.g. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`

[Guidelines for Using BIN and BIN2 Collations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143350(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Guidelines for Using BIN Collations
>
> If your SQL Server applications interact with older versions of SQL Server that use binary collations, continue to use binary. Binary collations might be a more suitable choice for mixed environments.

---

> For similar reasons to what has just been stated regarding the *BIN2 collations, unless you have specific requirements to maintain backwards-compatibility behavior, you should lean towards using the Windows collations and not the SQL Server-specific collations (i.e. the ones starting with SQL* are now considered kinda "sucky" ;-) ).
>   
>  - [@srutzky - Latin1_General_BIN performance impact when changing the database default collation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110944/43889)

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KIIDYH74471

```
create table t (
    a varchar(16)  --collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS /* default */
  , b varchar(16)  --collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  , c nvarchar(16) --collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  , d nvarchar(16) --collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
);
insert into t values ('ss','ß',N'ss',N'ß');
select *
    , case when a = b then '=' else '!=' end as [a=b] /* != */
    , case when a = d then '=' else '!=' end as [a=d] /* = */
    , case when c = b then '=' else '!=' end as [c=b] /* = */
    , case when c = d then '=' else '!=' end as [c=d] /* = */
from t;
```

returns:

```
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| a  | b | c  | d | a=b | a=d | c=b | c=d |
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ss | ß | ss | ß | !=  | =   | =   | =   |
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

```
create table t (
    a varchar(16)  collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
  , b varchar(16)  collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
  , c nvarchar(16) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
  , d nvarchar(16) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
);
insert into t values ('ss','ß',N'ss',N'ß');
select *
    , case when a = b then '=' else '!=' end as [a=b] /* != */
    , case when a = d then '=' else '!=' end as [a=d] /* != */
    , case when c = b then '=' else '!=' end as [c=b] /* != */
    , case when c = d then '=' else '!=' end as [c=d] /* != */
from t;
```

returns:

```
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| a  | b | c  | d | a=b | a=d | c=b | c=d |
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ss | ß | ss | ß | !=  | !=  | !=  | !=  |
+----+---+----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sharing the other resources. After going through the answers from the [other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110911/latin1-general-bin-performance-impact-when-changing-the-database-default-collati), it seems that changing the collation of the database (also the collation of the textual columns of the existing tables) results in more consistent results and better performance. Is that how it is generally done?

Comment: @SayanPal I would have to say it depends, but I'll see if I can get srutzky to offer some advice.