# SQL Server 2017 Collation for special character (Hawaiian 'Okina) leads to "?" string behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-collation

I need to insert some Hawaiian 'Okina string name as 'Kapiʻolani'; However in the SQL Server 2017 database it shows like `Kapi?olani` with a question mark.

I did some research and tried like this [article's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455166/special-character-hawaiian-okina-leads-to-weird-string-behavior):

```
CREATE TABLE Organization3 (Name NVARCHAR(250) COLLATE Japanese_XJIS_140_BIN2);
```

After insert value:

```
INSERT INTO Organization3 
      ([Name])
      values
      ('Kapi''olani')
update unicas_config.dbo.Organization3  set Name = 'Kapiʻolani'
```

It still shows like this: `Kapi?olani` (with question mark).

Is any solution to make it show correctly? Thank you so much

Comment: You need to use `set Name = N'Kapiʻolani'` i.e. tell it you are inserting a nvarchar rather than a varchar.

Comment: @DaleK It works! Thank you so much

Comment: @DaleK Can I ask if I need " ʻ ", do I need to set Collation to any of them which can support Unicode?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking. But try it and see!

Comment: @DaleK, I did and it works!  Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the N prefix (i.e. `N'Kapiʻolani'`) to specify that it's an Unicode string (as already pointed out in the comments).

The collation matters only for sorting and comparisons (as well as string-related functions that do comparisons to perform their task).

For example, the following SELECT-s return different results:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (x NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (N'Kapiʻolani'),(N'KAPIʻOLANI'),(N'Kapi''olani'),(N'Kapiolani'),(N'Kapi olani')

SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI), * FROM #t ORDER BY 1
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS), * FROM #t ORDER BY 1
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI), * FROM #t ORDER BY 1
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS), * FROM #t ORDER BY 1
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY x COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN), * FROM #t ORDER BY 1

DROP TABLE #t
```

Use the collation that returns the data that you are expecting.